# PEAR Mail not sending after upgrade to PHP5.5

Tags: php, email

So, recently I updated from 5.3 to 5.5 to use the new password hash api; however PEAR mail is not working now.

Code:

```
public function email_user($email, $password) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    require '/usr/share/pear/Mail.php';
    $from    = 'Matthew Harris <user@domain.com>';
    $to      = $email;
    $subject = 'Lunch Club Password';
    $headers = array (
        'From'    => $from,
        'To'      => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject
    );
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host'     => $host,
        'auth'     => true,
        'username' => 'user@domain.com',
        'password' => 'password',
    ));
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
}
```

Error Log:

```
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: host in /var/www/html/hserv.org/public_html/inc/core.class.php on line 35
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: body in /var/www/html/hserv.org/public_html/inc/core.class.php on line 40
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 365
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 448
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 465
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 472
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 515
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 263
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 519
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 376
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 615
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 1266
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 263
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 1269
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 382
[30-Aug-2014 00:26:16 America/Chicago] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 249
```

There is nothing in the mail log and nothing else logging errors.

Comment: reviewing my post $host is not defined.... testing further.... will update

Comment: no luck... :( w/ $host